# How to check for database availability

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server, connection

I have the following code to test DB connection, it runs periodically to test for DB availability:

```
private bool CheckDbConn()
{
   SqlConnection conn = null;
   bool result = true;

   try
   {
       conn = DBConnection.getNewCon();
       ConnectionState conState = conn.State;

       if (conState == ConnectionState.Closed || conState == ConnectionState.Broken)
       {
          logger.Warn(LogTopicEnum.Agent, "Connection failed in DB connection test on CheckDBConnection");
          return false;
       }             
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      logger.Warn(LogTopicEnum.Agent, "Error in DB connection test on CheckDBConnection", ex);
      return false; // any error is considered as db connection error for now
   }
   finally
   {
      try
      {
         if (conn != null)
         {
            conn.Close();
         }
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
         logger.Warn(LogTopicEnum.Agent, "Error closing connection on CheckDBConnection", ex);
         result = false;
      }
   }
   return result;
}
```

And:

```
static public SqlConnection getNewCon()
{
    SqlConnection newCon = new SqlConnection();
    newCon.ConnectionString = DBConnection.ConnectionString; // m_con.ConnectionString;
    newCon.Open();
    return newCon;
}
```

My question is: will this work as expected?

Specifically, I'm concerned about the test of the `ConnectionState`. Is it possible that the state will be: connecting (since `Open()` is synchronous)?

What should I do in that case?

Comment: I cannot comment so... ... also avoid catching general Exceptions "catch(Exception ex)" and try to catch specific exceptions like the examples above "catch(SqlException ex)"

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can try like this.

```
    public bool IsServerConnected()
    {
        using (var l_oConnection = new SqlConnection(DBConnection.ConnectionString))
        {
            try
            {
                l_oConnection.Open();
                return true;
            }
            catch (SqlException)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: what if l_oConnection.Close(); will throw an exception in the finally block?

Comment: using ... close and dispose the connection, no need to close then

Comment: I was using this but found it returned true on the first call after the database was taken offline. This was using .Net 3.5 against a sql server 2012 db.

Answer (score 13):

[`SqlConnection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.open.aspx) will throw a `SqlException` when it cannot connect to the server.

```
public static class SqlExtensions
{
    public static bool IsAvailable(this SqlConnection connection)
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            connection.Close();
        }
        catch(SqlException)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
using(SqlConnection connection = GetConnection())
{
    if(connection.IsAvailable())
    {
        // Success
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Your code seems fine, but you really need to use the IDisposable pattern, and some naming convention too:

```
private bool CheckDbConnection(string connectionString)
{
    try
    {
        using(var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            return true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        logger.Warn(LogTopicEnum.Agent, "Error in DB connection test on CheckDBConnection", ex);
        return false; // any error is considered as db connection error for now
    }
}
```

And `connection.Close()` is not supposed to throw. Just use the `using` block and your are fine.

No need to test the `Close` state, since you have just opened it.
[More about the `Broken` state:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.connectionstate.aspx)

> Broken    The connection to the data source is broken. This can occur
>   only after the connection has been opened. A connection in this state
>   may be closed and then re-opened. (This value is reserved for future
>   versions of the product.)

So really, no need to test that.

The `Connecting` state could be catch if you are in a multithread context and your instance of connection is shared. But it is not your case here.

Answer (score 3):

This code does not block a UI if called.

```
public static class DatabaseExtensions
{
    public static async Task<bool> IsConnectionViable(this string connectionStr)
    {
        await using var sqlConn = new SqlConnection(connectionStr);
        return await sqlConn.IsConnectionViable();
    }

    public static async Task<bool> IsConnectionViable(this SqlConnection connection)
    {
        var isConnected = false;

        try
        {
            await connection.OpenAsync();
            isConnected = (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // ignored
        }

        return isConnected;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

actually, in visual studio, connection class has sonnectionstate property.

when connection state changes, connections statechange event is been trigerred.

you might want to check this article.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa326268(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Not sure how it's related to visual studio , plus if you look at the post , it has connectionState in it...

Answer (score 0):

This code is for Mysql.

```
public class Program
{
string connection = "SERVER=localhost; user id=root; password=; database=dbname";
private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
checkifconnected();
}

private void checkifconnected()
{
MySqlConnection connect = new MySqlConnection(connection);
try{
connect.Open();
MessageBox.Show("Database connected");
}
catch
{
MessageBox.Show("you are not connected to database");
}
}

public static void Main()
{

}
}
```