# create a test connection button in mvc view for different servers added at run time

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, sql-server-2012

I was trying to adding connection strings at runtime, one the data is added successfully then I want to test/verify those parameters by clicking on test connection. Need help how I can check this connection

something like [image]

Comment: Test what connection? All you have mentioned is some strings and a button. Question is far too broad

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16171144/how-to-check-for-database-availability
maybe this can help you

Comment: Thanks @Daniel Its good reference